# Can I put a magnetically shielded speaker in my tower and run it from my sound card?

Tags: audio, speakers, case-mods

As my question states, can I place a magnetically shielded speaker (it's a center channel fullrange, rated for more than 10 watts) and be safe with putting it in my PC (and avoiding shorts), and using it for music, by running it off of my sound card?

My sound card is the Creative CT4810 (It's identified as Sound Blaster PCI but Googling the model number shows the Vibra 128), with the jumpers set for speaker out (a TDA1517 2x6W amplifier on the sound card).

Comment: Magnetic shielding would not be needed, unless you use floppies, but I would be concerned about vibrations jiggling RAM modules loose. Also, most PC cases make poor loudspeaker enclosures from an acoustic point of view. A metal case might rattle.

Comment: Also HDD, which is much more sensitive to vibration than solid state components. That said, at **moderate** volume, it should not be an issue.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can.  Computers often come with unshielded speakers in them already.

As mentioned in the comments to your question, would it sound good? I Guess you will have to find out.

It would take an *incredibly* powerful magnet that is *moving* to induce an electric current to disrupt or damage components.
See this [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_yEu2R1gYSs) showing a *monster* rare earth magnet versus electrical devices, including a computer.  Electronics hold up very well.